# call one constructor from another in java

Tags: java, constructor

This was the question asked in interview.
Can we call one constructor from another if a class has multiple constructors in java and when?How can I call I mean syntax?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Multiple constructors are there to create the objects differently and can be called from other classes. They are made just for that purpose.

Comment: he means calling a constructor from another one.

Comment: he's asking whether it is allowed to call a constructor from another constructor or not whenever a class has more than one constructor

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can, and the syntax I know is

```
this(< argument list >);
```

You can also call a super class' constructor through

```
super(< argument list >);
```

Both such calls can only be done as the first statement in the constructor (so you can only call one other constructor, and before anything else is done).

Comment: And you can't do anything that requires a reference to this.

Comment: it also must be in the first line of the constructor

Comment: yes, first line so it will be the first to be implemented

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can do that.

Have a look at the `ArrayList` implementation for example:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this(10);
}
```

The second constructor calls the first one with a `default capacity` of ten.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers are complete, so I'm adding this one to fill in the blanks.

You can call one constructor from another in the same class, or call the super class, with the following restrictions:

1. It has to be the first line of code in the calling constructor.
2. It cannot have any explicit or implicit reference to `this`. So you cannot pass an inner class (even an anonymous one if it references any instance methods), or the result of a non-static method call, as a parameter.

The syntax (as mentioned by others) is:

```
MyClass() {
   someInitialization();
}

MyClass(String s) { 
     this();
     doSomethingWithS(s);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

FYI, this is called the [telescoping/telescopic constructor pattern](http://theyjustdidit.com/telescopic-constructor-pattern/).

It's discussed in [JLS 8.8.7.1 Explicit Constructor Invokations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7.1)

> - *Alternate constructor invocations* begin with the keyword `this` (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
> - *Superclass constructor invocations* begin with either the keyword `super` (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments) or a Primary expression. They are used to invoke a constructor of the direct superclass.

Answer (score 7):

```
this(other, args);
```

Comment: This is either misleading or just plain wrong!  What is other?  You simply invoke the other constructor using `this(args-required-by-constructor)` or `super(args-required-by-constructor);`

Answer (score 6):

example:

```
public class FileDb {

  /**
   * 
   */
  public FileDb() {
    this(null);
  }

  public FileDb(String filename) {
    // ...
  }

}
```